# Browserify + third-party plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, browserify

I am trying to wrap my head around Browserify. Presently I have this file:

```
window.URI = require('urijs');
window._ = require('underscore');
window.moment = require('moment');
window.Cookies = require('js-cookie');
window.tinymce = require('tinymce/tinymce');

if (window.$ === undefined || window.jQuery === undefined) {
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
}
```

I have access to jQuery through $ and it works just fine. My main problem is with tinymce.

How can I get it to work with Browserify? As you can imagine, the following doesn't work.

```
tinymce.init({
    selector : "textarea",
    toolbar : "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image jbimages",
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem in React. you have to change

```
window.tinymce = require('tinymce/tinymce');
```

to

```
window.tinymce = require('tinymce/tinymce').tinymce.EditorManager;
```